# Azure Mobile Services scale pricing

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

I am trying to understand how Azure Mobile Services scaling work.

Below screenshot was taken from Mobile Services scale tab in Azure portal.
I am using **BASIC** tier.

[image]

1. When setting SCALE-BY METRIC to NONE, we will pay at a "minimum" UNIT COUNT * $14.99.
   For example, if i set UNIT COUNT to 6, then I'll pay 6 * $14.99 = $89.94 every month no matter how much API calls are being made, is my understanding correct?
2. When setting SCALE-BY METRIC to API CALLS, we can set minimum UNIT COUNT and maximum UNIT COUNT, this is suitable if at some days we have few api calls but in other days we have more api calls, is this correct?
3. Before moving from development to production, how do we anticipate which scaling option to use? Continuously monitor the API count and change the scaling option when we think we will go over the limit?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not affiliated with MS or Azure, so these answers are from my personal understanding.

1. Yes this is my understanding as well. You can also check this behaviour by extrapolating the predicted costs in your bill.
2. Yes.
3. I have a few apps running on Windows Azure Mobile Services in the Store. Usually I start out by trying to estimate the typical api calls per session. This can be done quite easily as long as you are in development. This should give you an idea about how many users an instance can support. Example: In one of my simpler apps one instance could serve about 800-1000 daily active users. Now, even with this information I usually set the scaling to the maximum for launch day, just to anticipate anything. In case it scales to the maximum it'll most likely be just for a day - and if it isn't well in that case congrats!

Comment: Thanks, do you know what constitutes an API Call?
I created a mobile service from scratch (0 API calls initially), created a custom API, then called this custom API only once and waited for 10 mins or so, on my dashboard i get 13 Calls in total for API call. I would expect to only get 1 call only..

Comment: It should only be external, incoming requests. Some examples: Custom API calls, Table API calls, possibly authentication requests. It could also include some setup calls: fetching a mobile service table etc. On the other hand I have found it noteworthy that using your own APIs in the backend still counts as one call: You dont have to bundle complex operations into a single API for fearing increased quota. Instead you can expose one API endpoint and have it call whatever you need on your end... Regarding the 13 calls: Might be setup calls, auth? Still seems like a lot though.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation. I am currently using FREE tier, and I have used web debugging tool to send REST request for testing. I am now over the capacity of 16667 CALLS / DAY, but how come I can still send REST request successfully? i am on 18xxx calls now.

Comment: The mobile service quotas are fairly generous. There used to be times where Microsoft employees openly admitted that even when the quotas would be surpassed absolutely nothing would happen. Not sure if thats still the case today, though.

Comment: oh yeah, I remember last time my API Call went "way" over and received an email from Microsoft suggesting I should upgrade my tier.